# CQ5 widget with xtype hidden

Tags: aem

I am trying to add a hidden property (key-value pair) to a page using a 'hidden' xtype in the page properties. But the property always returns a null/blank

The widget code is as below.

```
<vanitycheck
        jcr:primaryType="cq:Widget"
        defaultValue="myValue"
        hidden="{Boolean}true"
        name="./myKey"
        value="myValue"
        xtype="hidden"/>
```

The JSP code is as below:

```
<%=currentPage.getProperties().get("myKey" , "") %>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Are you opening the dialog? The default values held in the `dialog.xml` will only get applied after editing the component & saving it (i.e. the dialog has to be brought into play — they're defaults for the dialog itself, not the JCR).

If you want a default value held in the JCR when the component is created, put a `cq:template.xml` file in your component alongside your `dialog.xml`. This will specify default properties that get added into the node on creation.

E.g., you could have a file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jcr:root xmlns:cq="http://www.day.com/jcr/cq/1.0" 
          xmlns:jcr="http://www.jcp.org/jcr/1.0" 
          xmlns:nt="http://www.jcp.org/jcr/nt/1.0"
    jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
    defaultValue="myValue"/>
```

---

**EDIT:**

For default values within templates, edit the `.content.xml` file under `/apps/[your-design]/[template-name]/.content.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jcr:root xmlns:sling="http://sling.apache.org/jcr/sling/1.0" 
          xmlns:cq="http://www.day.com/jcr/cq/1.0"
          xmlns:jcr="http://www.jcp.org/jcr/1.0" 
          jcr:primaryType="cq:Template"
          jcr:title="Content Page Template">
    <jcr:content
        jcr:primaryType="cq:PageContent"
        sling:resourceType="foo/components/page/bar"
        defaultValue="myValue"/>
</jcr:root>
```

Either of these solutions though will only work on newly created content (i.e. a new component for `cq:template.xml` or new page with `.content.xml`).

For existing pages, default values in the dialog can be used, as you suggested; but since these values only get loaded when the dialog is opened & saved to the JCR on "OK" within the dialog, it requires the user to edit the Page Properties on each page in order to persist the values to the JCR.

If this isn't suitable, using a fallback value in the JSP/class might be the preferred solution: `resource.get(defaultValue, "myValue");`

Comment: Actually, I want the property to be non-editable (hence, hidden) and added to the page properties. There is an existing dialog in the page and  I intend to add my property in that.

Comment: HI Riju, using a cq:template.xml file would make the property non-editable without needing to add it to the `dialog.xml`. For page templates, you could code similarly within `/apps/foo/templates/templateName/.content.xml`, but this approach will only work on newly created pages. For existing pages, your solution should work, but it will require the editor to open the dialog so that this value is loaded in, before it gets saved to the JCR on "OK". You won't be able to use the dialog to add existing properties on the page, without the user interacting with the dialog.

Comment: @anotherdave what are the pros/cons of the two different solutions you have provided?

Comment: @Behrang Generally I'd prefer the `cq:template.xml` approach, as the property is stored against the node in the JCR as soon as the component is created (important for things like search indexes). The drawback is that it will only work when content is initially created. I don't think there's an advantage of using the `defaultValue` property within the dialog, it's just another approach that could be taken — the disadvantage is that it does require editor intervention (to open the dialog & save it so that the defaults from ExtJS get applied into the JCR.

Comment: @anotherdave Thanks Dave. By the way is `cq:template` documented anywhere? Can't find anything about it in the docs. Also is it used by any of the built-in components?

Comment: @Behrang It's mentioned in this blog post here by Feike Visser, though I haven't seen it in documentation proper, as far as I can remember http://dev.day.com/cemblog/en/experiencedelivers/2012/06/defaults-in-your-component.html On OOTB components, the `/libs/collab/calendar/components/calendar` seems to include one, though it seems only to be used to specify "sling:resourceTypes" rather than other properties.

Comment: @anotherdave: Looks like this won't work in Touch UI.